# How to evaluate the integration with exponential and get the $4\pi$ from it

Tags: integration

I know $\int \frac{e^{-kr}}{r}  d^3r = \frac{4\pi}{k^2}$. 
What technique should I use? Why the $4\pi$ appear?

$d^3r$ is a volume integral with ($r = |r|$) between the distance. For example, as Kobe wrote in cartesian coordinate. But I think I should evaluate in other coordinates.

Comment: What is $d^3r$? How do you defined it? Where did you derive this equation from?

Comment: For clarification, is $\int \frac{e^{-kr}}{r}\,d^3r$ the same as$$\iiint_{\Bbb R^3} \frac{e^{-k\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}}}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}}\, dx\, dy\, dz?$$

Comment: @kobe yes in cartisan coordinate yes.

Comment: This is because $4\pi$ is the surface of the unit sphere hence, for every radially symmetric function, $$\int_{\mathbb R^3}f\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\right)dxdydz=4\pi\int_0^\infty f(r)r^2dr$$

Comment: @Did, but is the square root make any difference in your expression?

Comment: No. Why should it? If you prefer, $$\int_{\mathbb R^3}f\left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)dxdydz=4\pi\int_0^\infty f(r^2)r^2dr$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using spherical coordinates,

$$\int \frac{e^{-kr}}{r}\, d^3r = \int_0^\infty \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^\pi \frac{e^{-kr}}{r}\, r^2\sin \phi\, d\phi\, d\theta\, dr = 4\pi \int_0^\infty e^{-kr} r\, dr$$

By the u-substitution $u = kr$,

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-kr} r\, dr = \frac{1}{k^2}\int_0^\infty e^{-u}u du$$

Integration by parts yields

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-u} u\, du = u(e^{-u})\bigg|_{u = 0}^\infty +\int_0^\infty e^{-u}\, du= 1$$

Hence

$$\int \frac{e^{-kr}}{r}\, d^3r = \frac{4\pi}{k^2}$$

as desired.